# Jaxb customization of nillable attribute value for a specific field

Tags: java, xml, xsd, jaxb

I'm working with an XSD schema file (that I cannot change) that defines element XXX as following:

`<xsd:element name="XXX" type="Date" minOccurs="0"/>`
This produces a java.util.Date in the generated class.

I would need to change how the field is marshalled to XML: if the attribute is null, I would like to produce an empty tag, like if the xsd was:

`<xsd:element name="XXX" type="Date" minOccurs="0" nillable=true/>`
This produces a JaxbElement in the generated class.

Is it possible to do something like this via Jaxb bindings?

Regards
Giulio

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suggestions:

- Pre-process your schema with an XSLT to add `nillable` where you need it.
- Use the `jaxb2-simplify-plugin` and customize your element with `simplify:as-reference-property`. I have actually never tried that but maybe it'll work.
- Write an XJC plugin.

ps. I'm the author of the mentioned [jaxb2-simplify-plugin](https://github.com/highsource/jaxb2-basics/wiki/JAXB2-Simplify-Plugin).

Comment: I applied XSLT transformation using maven XML plugin and it worked :) I didn't try with your plugin because first option worked immediately

Answer (score 3):

Yes you can.. but isn't a good practice.

```
<bindings node="//xs:element[@name='XXX']">
    <property name="xxx">
        <baseType> 
            <javaType name= "javax.xml.bind.JAXBElement&lt;java.util.Date&gt;"/>
        </baseType>
    </property>
</bindings>
```

you should add also below attributes within `<javaType>` [See here Documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnbbf.html)

- parseMethod is the name of the parse method to be called during
  unmarshalling.
- printMethod is the name of the print method to be
  called during marshalling.

Comment: I tried to play a little bit with your solution but for me it was too complicated to make it work (I also needed to add some java code to make it work). Thanks anyway ;)